# Focus on an input after creating it

Tags: jquery

I would like to substitute a text input for a password input after clicking on the first one, my code creates it but it doesnt have focus on the new input, I would like to change this.

Here's my code.

```
$('.input_center input:text').click(function(){
var padre = $(this).parent();
                var passInput = $(document.createElement("div"));
                passInput.html('<input type="password">');
                padre.append(passInput);
                passInput.focus();
                $(this).remove();
});
```

That passInput.focus() is not doing the focus, so I dont know how to get it done.

Comment: how about setting a timeout like setTimeout(function(){passInput.focus()}, 400) ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It sounds like a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var v = $('<div><input class="pwd" type="password" /></div');
padre.appendTo(v);
$('.pwd').focus();
```

It might help to add then recall the code to get focus.

Answer (score 7):

`passInput` is the `<div>` element, not the `<input>`, which is why it can't get focus.

Change it to this:

```
passInput.find("input").focus();
```

You could actually rewrite that whole function into one chained statement like so:

```
$(this)
    .parent()
    .append($(document.createElement("div"))
        .append($('<input type="password">').focus())
    )
    .end()
    .remove();
```

*Though, off the top of my head, I don't know if it will work to `.focus()` an element before it gets added to the DOM.*